# replace object at indexPath - big array with 12 sections

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have an array with 12 sections and i need to replace value at index.
My test code:

```
NSMutableArray *hm = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@{@"first": @[@"test1", @"test2"]}, @{@"second": @[@"test1"]}, nil];

NSLog(@"%@", [hm valueForKey:@"first"][0][0] );

[[hm valueForKey:@"first"][0] replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:@"lol"];

NSLog(@"%@", hm);
```

First NSLog returns : `test1` - its ok

When replace `- crash with -[__NSArrayI replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fde53d2f700`

I need to change test1 to something.

Wha am i doing wrong please?

Comment: Your inner arrays are immutable (`NSArray`) and you need then to be mutable (`NSMutableArray`). It will get much more simple if you avoid nested arrays and use custom objects instead.

Comment: hm is mutable array. When use [ hm replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:@"lol"] - it returns lol and second

Comment: Your _inner_ arrays are immutable, e.g. `@[@"test1", @"test2"]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *hm = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@{@"first": @[@"test1", @"test2"]}, @{@"second": @[@"test1"]}, nil];

    NSLog(@"%@", [hm valueForKey:@"first"][0][0] );

    //Your inner array is immutable, change it to mutable and replace the object, That's it.
    NSMutableArray *array = [[hm valueForKey:@"first"][0] mutableCopy];
    [array replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:@"lol"];
    [hm replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:array];

    NSLog(@"%@", hm);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initwithArray[[hm objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"first"]];
[arr replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:@"lol"];
[hm replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:arr];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make mutable dictionary and array structure

```
NSMutableArray* names = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                         [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          @"Joe",@"firstname",
                          @"Bloggs",@"surname",
                          nil],
                         [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          @"Simon",@"firstname",
                          @"Templar",@"surname",
                          nil],
                         [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          @"Amelia",@"firstname",
                          @"Pond",@"surname",
                          nil],
                         nil];

NSLog(@"Before - %@",names);


[names replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                          @"Joe_New",@"firstname",
                                          @"Bloggs_New",@"surname",
                                          nil]];

NSLog(@"After - %@",names);
```

Before - (
        **{
        firstname = Joe;
        surname = Bloggs;
    }**,
        {
        firstname = Simon;
        surname = Templar;
    },
        {
        firstname = Amelia;
        surname = Pond;
    }
)

After - (
        **{
        firstname = "Joe_New";
        surname = "Bloggs_New";
    }**,
        {
        firstname = Simon;
        surname = Templar;
    },
        {
        firstname = Amelia;
        surname = Pond;
    }
)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *hm = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@{@"first": @[@"test1", @"test2"]}, @{@"second": @[@"test1"]}, nil];

    NSMutableDictionary *dic=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[hm objectAtIndex:0]];
    NSMutableArray *array=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[dic objectForKey:@"first"]];
    [array replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:@"lol"];

    [dic setObject:array forKey:@"first"];

    [hm replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:array];





 O/P  (ViewController.m:48) (
            (
            lol,
            test2
        ),
            {
            second =         (
                test1
            );
        }
    )
```